# FullText Index - Searching values from another table

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search, contains, full-text-indexing

Is it possible, in SQL Server 2008, using the full text index syntax, to run a query such as this one?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_TO_SEARCH S,
TABLE_WITH_STRINGS_TO_SEARCH SS
WHERE 
   CONTAINS(S.WHOLE_NAME,SS.FIRST_NAME) 
OR CONTAINS(S.WHOLE_NAME,SS.LAST_NAME)
```

I need to search for the FIRST_NAME in table TABLE_TO_SEARCH, column WHOLE_NAME that has an full text index on it. It doesn't seem to be a valid query though... Is there any workaround to it by using the full text index search?

**LATER EDIT:**

Here is the business case: each night I am downloading from several websites information about "blacklisted" individuals and insert it into a table in this format: `WholeName, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName`. But the data is chaotic as `WholeName` does not necessarily contain either the last, first or middle name or the WholeName is null while the other 3 fields have values, or every of these 4 fields is null and so on. Also, the data may repeat itself as one blacklisted individual may come from 2+ of these websites. What I need to do is to compare this data, as chaotic as it is, against our customer data based on our customer's `First` and `Last` name and give it a matching score (rank) against the files we download from these websites.

First I tried with `charindex` or `like` operators but I couldn't create a scoring algorithm based on this and also it took 6 hours to compare just our customer's first and last name with only the `WholeName` column from the `TABLE_TO_SEARCH` table. I thought that perhaps implementing the full_text index it would get easier and faster but ... apparently I was wrong.

Has anyone dealt with a task like this? And if so, what was the best approach?

Comment: What about the query doesn't seem to be valid?

Comment: It's not a valid query syntax.

Comment: Not clear which table needs to score.  Do you want a best score compared to the other table?  Do you need to know which row the score is associated with.   Size of the tables?

Comment: I need to check the values from the `TABLE_WITH_STRINGS_TO_SEARCH` (LastName, FirstName) in the `TABLE_TO_SEARCH` table. Based on the chars match I need to provide a ranking to it (same as how the ranking works when using the `FREETEXTTABLE` or the `CONTAINSTABLE` with a full text index).

Comment: Then why not use FREETEXTTABLE or the CONTAINSTABLE?

Answer (score 1):

After skimming http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx I don't think it is possible to do your search in this way. Not only that, but it seems this type of index wouldn't work well with names anyway.

If you care about checking one name then all you have to do is set those values to variables. This method would allow you to use the full-text index.

Otherwise, I would suggest splitting the WHOLE_NAME column (if there is a space or unique character between the first and last name) and comparing each part to those other columns. If you are working with a huge data set, you may want to experiment with doing this at a temp table level and creating an index.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried doing that but it takes too long to do that; I tried going thru each name with a cursor and search for it in the full_text indexed column but in 1 hour it only went thru 20k names. And I have aprox 250k records in the TABLE_WITH_STRING_TO_SEARCH table and aprox 2.5 million records in the TABLE_TO_SEARCH table, so... it's not a valid option. Also, in TABLE_TO_SEARCH I do have first, last, middle name but the data in there is chaotic because it contains data inserted from several different web sites.